# Angular4: ¿Porque no realiza peticion http el servicio?

Tags: http-post, angular4

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers,Response } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
@Injectable()
export class LugaresService {
  // private instance variable to hold base url
  private serviceUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/ProgramaHospitalServicios/service';
  // Resolve HTTP using the constructor
  constructor (private http: Http) {}

    public getLugares(){
    var data:any = {};
    const headers = new Headers({"Content-Type":"application/json"});
    debugger;
    var body:any = {
      "service":"getLugares",
      "params": {}
    };
    this.http.post(this.serviceUrl, body, {headers:headers})
      .map((resultado)=> {
        console.log(resultado);
        debugger;
        data = resultado.json().lugares;
        debugger;
        console.log(data);
      } )
      .catch(this.handleError); // Trouble line.
      return data;
  }  

  public handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
  }
  public buscarLugar(id){
    console.log(id);
    const headers = new Headers({"Content-Type":"application/json"});
    var body:any = {
      "service":"getLugar",
      "params":  {
                  "id":id
                  }
    };
    this.http.post(this.serviceUrl, body, {headers:headers})
      .map((resultado)=> {
        const data = resultado.json().lugar;
        console.log(data);
        return data;
      })
  }
  public guardarLugar(lugar){
    console.log(lugar);
    const headers = new Headers({"Content-Type":"application/json"});
    var body:any = {
      "service":"putLugares",
      "params": {
                  "nombre": lugar.nombre,
                  "cercania": lugar.cercania,
                  "distancia": lugar.distancia,
                  "descripcion": lugar.descripcion,
                  "plan": lugar.plan
                 }
    };
    this.http.post(this.serviceUrl, body, {headers:headers})
      .map((resultado)=> {
        const data = resultado.json().lugares;
        console.log(data);
        return data;
      })
  }
}
```

**El código que llama**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LugaresService } from '../services/lugares.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lugares',
  templateUrl: './lugares.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lugares.component.css']
})
export class LugaresComponent {
  title = 'Lugares';
  lat:number = 40.931910;
  lng:number = -4.117217;
  lugares = null; 
  constructor(private lugaresService: LugaresService){
    this.lugares = lugaresService.getLugares()
    .subscribe(lugares=>{
      this.lugares=lugares;
      var me = this;
      me.lugares = Object.keys(me.lugares).map(function (key){return me.lugares[key]});
    }, error=>{
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? ¿Cómo es el código que llama al método que no te funciona?

Comment: No da error, simplemente no realiza la peticion

Comment: El metodo es getLugares

Comment: He probado la infraestructura java / servlets con jmeter y funciona

Comment: Añade el código a la pregunta, no pongas comentarios extras (edita)

Comment: lo siento, soy nuevo

Answer (score 1):

Debes probar añadiendo un tipo a su función getLugares a mostrar al compiler con previsión cual tipo de valor ella va a devolver. Por ejemplo (pues en este caso se trata de un Observable):

```
public getLugares(): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.post(this.serviceUrl, body, {headers:headers})
    .map((resultado)=> {
      console.log(resultado);
      return resultado.json().lugares;
    }).catch(this.handleError); 
}
```

También, hay alguna razón que te neccesites el observable que sería devuelto del 'getLugares' asignado a this.lugares? Esto puede ser problematico a pesar del variable 'this.lugares' no tiene tipo y además, el valor que contiene sería borrado al instante que ejecuta la función map. Si fuera yo, probaría así:

```
lugaresService.getLugares()
  .subscribe(lugares=>{
    this.lugares=lugares;
    var me = this;
    me.lugares = Object.keys(me.lugares).map(function (key){return 
      me.lugares[key]});
  }, error=>{
    console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu método hace la petición pero devuelve un objeto vacío porque no tienes en cuenta que `map` se ejecutará de manera asíncrona.
Prueba con algo como esto, devolviendo un Observable:

```
  public getLugares(){

    const headers = new Headers({"Content-Type":"application/json"});
    debugger;
    var body:any = {
      "service":"getLugares",
      "params": {}
    };
    return this.http.post(this.serviceUrl, body, {headers:headers})
      .map((resultado)=> {
        console.log(resultado);
        return resultado.json().lugares;
      }).catch(this.handleError); 

  }
```

Comment: Failed to compile.

D:/node/myapp3/src/app/lugares/lugares.component.ts (16,6): Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.

Comment: En el método superior

Answer (score 0):

**lugares.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LugaresService } from '../services/lugares.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/animations'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lugares',
  templateUrl: './lugares.component.html',
  animations: [
    trigger('contenedorAnimable', [
       state('inicial', style({
         opacity:0
       })),
       state('final', style({
         opacity:1
       })),
       transition('inicial => final', animate(2000)),
       transition('final => inicial', animate(1000))
      ])
  ]})

export class LugaresComponent {
  title = 'Lugares';
  state = 'inicial';
  lat:number = 40.931910;
  lng:number = -4.117217;
  lugares=[];
  animar(){
    this.state = (this.state === 'final') ? 'inicial' : 'final';
  }
  animacionInicia(e){
    console.log('Iniciado!')
  }
  constructor(private lugaresService: LugaresService){
    lugaresService.getLugares(this);
    this.state = 'final';
   }
}
```

**lugares.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers,Response } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
@Injectable()
export class LugaresService {
  // private instance variable to hold base url
  private serviceUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/ProgramaHospitalServicios/service';
  // Resolve HTTP using the constructor
  private lugares = [];
  constructor (private http: Http) {}

    public getLugares(parent):any{

    const headers = new Headers({"Content-Type":"application/json"});

    var body:any = {
      "service":"getLugares",
      "params": {}
    };

    this.http.post(this.serviceUrl, body, {headers:headers})
    .subscribe(lugares=>{
        this.lugares=lugares.json();
        var me = this;
        this.lugares=Object.keys(me.lugares)
          .map(function (key){
            return me.lugares[key]
          });
          parent.lugares=this.lugares[0];
    }, err => { 
      return err; 
    });
  }  


  public getLugar(id):any{
    console.log(id);
    const headers = new Headers({"Content-Type":"application/json"});
    var body:any = {
      "service":"getLugar",
      "params":  {
                  "id":id
                  }
    };
    return this.http.post(this.serviceUrl, body, {headers:headers})
      .subscribe(response=>{
        console.log(response.json().lugar[0]);
        return response.json().lugar[0];
    }, err => { 
      console.log("status: " + err.status + ", Error: " + err._body);
      return null;
    });
  }
  public guardarLugar(parent){
    console.log(parent.lugar);

    const headers = new Headers({"Content-Type":"application/json"});
    if (parent.lugar.id=='new'){
    var body:any = {
        "service":"putLugares",
        "params": { 
                  "nombre": parent.lugar.nombre,
                  "descripcion": parent.lugar.descripcion,
                  "calle": parent.lugar.calle,
                  "ciudad": parent.lugar.ciudad,
                  "pais": parent.lugar.pais,
                  "lat": parent.lugar.lat,
                  "lng": parent.lugar.lng,
                  "plan": parent.lugar.plan,
                  "active": parent.lugar.active
                 }
      };
      this.http.post(this.serviceUrl, body, {headers:headers})
       .subscribe(lugar=>{
          parent.lugar=lugar.json();  
          parent.warning = "Se añadió con exito."
      }, err => { 
        console.log("status: " + err.status + ", Error: " + err._body);
        parent.warning = "status: " + err.status + ", Error: " + err._body;
      });
    } else {
      var body:any = {
        "service":"updLugares",
        "params": { 
                  "nombre": parent.lugar.nombre,
                  "descripcion": parent.lugar.descripcion,
                  "calle": parent.lugar.calle,
                  "ciudad": parent.lugar.ciudad,
                  "pais": parent.lugar.pais,
                  "lat": parent.lugar.lat,
                  "lng": parent.lugar.lng,
                  "plan": parent.lugar.plan,
                  "active": parent.lugar.active,
                  "id": parseInt(parent.lugar.id)
                 }
      };
      this.http.post(this.serviceUrl, body, {headers:headers})
       .subscribe(lugar=>{
          parent.lugar=lugar.json();  
          parent.warning = "Se actualizó con exito."
      }, err => { 
        console.log("status: " + err.status + ", Error: " + err._body);
        parent.warning = "status: " + err.status + ", Error: " + err._body;
      });
    }

  }
  public obtenerGeoData(direccion:string){
    return this.http.get('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+direccion);
  }
}
```

Comment: ya funciona, que alguien lo cierre